# Make property non-optional if it was passed in object literal

Tags: typescript

Consider the following example ([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4AqA%20ZAbwFgAoZC5Aa1ABMAuZAZzClAHMBuMy5ANzgAbAK4QA-IxzdSAXx5kYwkAjDB0IZDEy48ACgAOUdPqaMA8gFtgYLBmz4ANMgBENELWd4AlMkZ2dRDyUUBBgwlAahG4Mzlrozk4AdMmGxkwy0nKkCkoqahqQLGb6YACqIFQg6ADuILp8EshKlTUgPiTZsmQ5yqrqyIVgAHLCFgBG0PWMIKMTUO3dXZ1kCOosmpgAjMgAvBvouoQyXtKrIOtxAEy7%204cCIhCMACyXx9Jkg8VlFVW1unGbRL3UQnD4QFgjcaTK5AoQgzi8RG8AD0yOQWAAtFjkLR0ODkFUwMhVhZ9MBBBAgA))

```
interface Foo<T> {
    kind: string;
    value?: T;
}
 
function foo<T>(props: Omit<Foo<T>, "kind">) : Foo<T> {
    return {kind:"foo", ...props};
}

function testOptUnknown(v?: unknown) {

}

function testNumber(v: number) {

}


const foo1 = foo({});
const foo2 = foo({value: 42});

testOptUnknown(foo1.value);
testNumber(foo2.value);             // <--- does not compile
```

What I am trying to achieve is that the "builder"-function `foo` specialises `Foo`'s `value` to be non-optional if a given value for `value` was passed.

BTW. Turning `value?: T` into `value: T` will not work for me because I am using `exactOptionalPropertyTypes`.

Comment: Does that work for you: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4AqA+ZAbwFgAoZC5Aa1ABMAuZAZzClAHMBuMy5ANzgAbAK4QA-IxzdSAXx5kYwkAjDB0IZDExYAGgBpkOZBAAekELSbIA8gFtgYLBmw68BgEQ0L7vHgAUAA5Q6AFMkgCUyJLIAGREXgzIAORa6EkyRDyUUBBgwlAahAn07qnuBgB0VUEhTDLScqQKSipqGpAs1gFgAKogVCDoAO4gfnwSyEoDwyCRJE2yZM3KqurIHWAAcsK2AEbQY4wgO-tQc0uLCwjqLMgmyAC8meSUSXBJjACMZI1k1yC3ACejyIVQqJgMu0YSQATOkLn8bmBNJhPiDUn5CDJwtJ-rdUjDGM4sCw2CB2AQnhisTjEQDkakAMzozCYgQiCCMAAsMOx0jIGy6vX6gxGflSnwq7NEOOQAognW6fWmYoJUqEMukG22ewOTPVHNlvGNlCAA

Comment: @Lesiak, yeah looks good! `function foo<T extends Omit<Foo<unknown>, "kind">>(props: T) : T & {kind: 'foo'}` is even more compact for my use-case with "many" generics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a type parameter for the actually passed-in input parameter and use that type parameter to construct your return type. That way, the compiler will propagate its knowledge of the type of the actual argument:

```ts
interface Foo<T> {
    kind: string;
    value?: T;
}
 
function foo<X, T extends Omit<Foo<X>, "kind">>(props: T) : T & {kind: 'foo'} {
    return {kind:"foo", ...props};
}

function testOptUnknown(v?: unknown) {

}

function testNumber(v: number) {

}

const x = {
    'a': 1
}

const y = {...x, b: '2'}


const foo1 = foo({});
const foo2: Foo<string> = foo({});
const foo3 = foo({value: 42});

testOptUnknown(foo1.value); 
testOptUnknown(foo2.value);
testNumber(foo3.value);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=27&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4AqA%20ZAbwFgAoZC5Aa1ABMAuZAZzClAHMBuMy5ANzgAbAK4QA-IxzdSAXx5kYwkAjDB0IZDExYAGgBpkOZBAAekELSbIA8gFtgYLBmw68BgEQ0L7vHgAUAA5Q6AFMkgCUyJLIAGREXgzIAORa6EkyRDyUUBBgwlAahAn07qnuBgB0VUEhTDLScqQKSipqGpAs1gFgAKogVCDoAO4gfnwSyEoDwyCRJE2yZM3KqurIHWAAcsK2AEbQY4wgO-tQc0uLCwjqLMgmyAC8meSUSXBJjACMZI1k1yC3ACejyIVQqJgMu0YSQATOkLn8bmBNJhPiDUn5CDJwtJ-rdUjDGM4sCw2CB2AQnhisTjEQDkakAMzozCYgQiCCMAAsMOx0jIGy6vX6gxGflSnwq7NEOOQAognW6fWmYoJUqEMukG22ewOTPVHNlvGNlCAA)